# Phonegap Build - IOS Certificates error

Tags: ios, cordova, build, certificate

Build for IOS show:

Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching -

My certificates are the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - nothing changed, my certs were all valid, yet saw this failure message.  Can you try re-exporting the developer certificate (.p12) file?  That worked for me.  Export that, create a new provisioning profile, then create a new key in PG Build.